# The bug reporting process prevents me from reporting my bug

Tags: launchpad, ubuntu-bug

I read through the Reporing Bugs Community Wiki. I am unsure exactly what kind of package to report my bug against. The problem is that my USB sound device will only work if connected at boot, but not if I plug it in after. So, is it a USB bug, a sound bug, or a boot problem? I don't know.

So, according to the Wiki, it says:

> If you're not sure which package is affected by the bug, type
>   ubuntu-bug in the "Run Application" window and click Run

So I do exactly that. I'm given this dialog:

[image: Apport Dialog]

The only USB option is for storage devices, and I'm not sure if it's a sound problem or USB problem or what, so I go with "Other problem". But then I'm simply dismissed with a "No package specified" error.

[image: No package specified]

How was I supposed to specify a package when the reason I chose "Other problem" was because I'm not sure what's going on?

So I restart the bug reporting process, this time selecing "Sound/Audio related problems". I get this message:

[image: Pulse crash]

... but wait... Pulse hadn't crashed before I started the bug reporting process, so is it the bug reporting process itself that crashed Pulse, and if so, then isn't that separate from the bug I want to report?

At this point I've lost confidence in the bug reporting procedure. This is not the first time I have encountered the incredibly user-unfriendly Ubuntu bug reporting process, so I could go off on a rant about it. But I won't. What I really want is just to be able to plug my USB audio device in after booting and not think about Ubuntu bug policies and politics.

So... how can I report this bug without getting stonewalled and diverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report the pulseaudio crash, open page https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio with a web browser, click "Report a bug" and follow the directions.

To report the problem of the USB sound device being detected at boot but not at a later time, do the same but with the udev package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev.

If it turns out that another package is responsible for the malfunction then the report can always be reassigned.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative, but, sincerely, how am I, or any new user, supposed to know that I should report a USB bug under "udev"?

Comment: As a new user you don't know that. However, even if you don't know against what package you should file a report, you can still use the bug reporting tools to file a report against *some* package (e.g., as a last resort, against the "ubuntu" package) and then others will reassign the report to where it should be.