# Problems with libudev0 libudev0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0 libgudev-1.0-0:i386, BREAKS

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I get this problems when i run apt-upgrade

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libudev0 : Breaks: libudev0:i386 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.4) but 175-0ubuntu9.5 is installed
libudev0:i386 : Breaks: libudev0 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.5) but 175-0ubuntu9.4 is installe
```

I ran all commands I could come up with like `clean`, `autoclean`, `install -f`, `dist-upgrade` etc.

I think I need some more understanding of what this problem really is to solve it.

I tried to `remove libudev0 and libudev0:i386`

but it does not work either.

What is really going on here? I have had problems like `Depends on` but never `Breaks`

---

I tried to remove libudev0:i386 but failed:

```
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get remove libudev0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gvfs:i386 : Depends: libudev0:i386 (>= 147) but it is not going to be installed
libgudev-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libudev0:i386 (>= 165) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

---

sudo apt-get install -f gives:

```
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-kde-en kde-l10n-engb openjdk-7-jre-lib language-pack-kde-en-base nvidia-settings-319-updates
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libudev0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libudev0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/28.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libudev0 (--configure):
 libudev0:amd64 175-0ubuntu9.4 cannot be configured because libudev0:i386 is in a different version (175-0ubuntu9.5)
dpkg: error processing libudev0:i386 (--configure):
 libudev0:i386 175-0ubuntu9.5 cannot be configured because libudev0:amd64 is in a different version (175-0ubuntu9.4)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgudev-1.0-0:
 libgudev-1.0-0 depends on libudev0 (>= 165); however:
  Package libudev0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgudev-1.0-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgudev-1.0-0:i386:
 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 depends on libudev0 (>= 165); however:
  Package libudev0:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgudev-1.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on libudev0 (>= 175); however:
  Package libudev0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                     Errors were encountered while processing:
 libudev0
 libudev0:i386
 libgudev-1.0-0
 libgudev-1.0-0:i386
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$
```

---

Tried to hold the packages then autoremove:

```
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-mark hold libudev0
libudev0 set on hold.
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-mark hold libudev0:i386
libudev0:i386 set on hold.
buffalo@android-4c56l:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev0 : Breaks: libudev0:i386 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.4) but 175-0ubuntu9.5 is installed
 libudev0:i386 : Breaks: libudev0 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.5) but 175-0ubuntu9.4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: I tried this and posted the output, thanks for helping me out

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` command in your question.

Comment: Posted the output, hope it solves something

Answer (score 0):

Hold the packages `libudev0`,`libudev0:i386` from being upgraded.

```
sudo apt-mark hold libudev0
sudo apt-mark hold libudev0:i386
```

upgrade all installed packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now the error won't appears while upgrading.

Comment: Tried this. still the same error:(

Comment: now try my edit.

Comment: please reply soon.

Comment: still: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev0 : Breaks: libudev0:i386 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.4) but 175-0ubuntu9.5 is installed
 libudev0:i386 : Breaks: libudev0 (!= 175-0ubuntu9.5) but 175-0ubuntu9.4 is installed

while running, sudo apt-get upgrade, after running the apt-mark hold commands

Comment: Yes, post the output of `sudo apt-get purge -s libudev0*` in pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tsm3E4Py

Comment: post the output of `sudo dpkg -P libudev0`,
 `sudo dpkg -P libudev0:i386`
 `sudo dpkg -P libgudev-1.0-0`
 `sudo dpkg -P libgudev-1.0-0:i386` in pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vwVZg6Zp thanks for helping me:)

Comment: why you run all the commands inside `/var/lib/dpkg`? Get out from that.Open a new terminal and then run the above commands.

Comment: okey, thought it did not matter

Comment: No, it matters.

Comment: Still get the same errors as far as i can see:( http://pastebin.com/DrTtGQZ5, used a fresh shell and run everything from my home folder

Comment: everything seams to depend on libudev0 >= 147 or libgudev-1.0-0 >= 147. Chrome have slightly different problems maybe? : google-chrome-stable depends on libudev0 (>= 147) | libudev1 (>= 198); however:
  Package libudev0 is to be removed.
  Package libudev1 is not installed.

Comment: Final one `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libudev0` , `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libudev0:i386` , `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libgudev-1.0-0` and `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libgudev-1.0-0:i386`

Comment: After that install all the removed packages via `apt-get`

Comment: It could not remove anything. Fork failed because it could not allocate memory:S http://pastebin.com/Ghhdt6ek

Comment: Some info about my memory http://pastebin.com/mNYgTJgk. Its wired that it fails because of memory I think I have free disk and ram

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/253466/why-am-i-frequently-getting-this-cannot-allocate-memory-error